# why is my validator function to validate a formarray not called in angular 5?

Tags: angular5, angular-validation, angular-reactive-forms

Hi I am having an issue with a validator as it is not getting called.

Currently I am having an `Angular 5` component with a  `formgroup` defined in it. The `formgroup` has a form array element. Each element in the `formgroup` array is of type `FormGroup`. I have written a `validator` named `duplicateClientNameValidator`. however when i edit the form the `validator` is not getting called. so following is my component ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { duplicateClientNameValidator } from '../../shared';


@Component({
  selector: 'pc-account-service-provider-clients',
  templateUrl: './account-service-provider-clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account-service-provider-clients.component.scss']
})
export class AccountServiceProviderClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  formGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor( private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
        aliases: this.fb.array([]) 
       },[duplicateClientNameValidator('aliases')]);
  }

  get aliases() {
    return this.formGroup.get('aliases') as FormArray;
  }

  addAlias() {
    const formGroupNew: FormGroup = new FormGroup( {
          id: new FormControl( { value:'', disabled:false}),
          name: new FormControl({ value:'', disabled:false},[Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]),
          companyNumber: new FormControl({ value:'', disabled:false},Validators.maxLength(20))
      }
    );
    this.aliases.push(formGroupNew);
  }

removeItem( index :number){
    this.aliases.removeAt(index);
}

handleSubmit() {}


get cancelLink(): string {
  return  '/dashboard';
}

}
```

The following is the definition of my `validator` funtion `duplicateClientNameValidator`

```
export function duplicateClientNameValidator( serviceProviderClientControlArrayName: string):ValidationErrors | null {

 return (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {

         const aliases:FormArray =  <FormArray>control.get(serviceProviderClientControlArrayName);

         for(const formGrp of aliases.controls ) {
          const frmGroup: FormGroup = <FormGroup> formGrp;
          console.log(frmGroup.get('name').value);
         }
      return null;
  };

}
```

The following is the snap of the UI . I can use the `+` icon to add new items into the `formgroup` and after editing all the field i am expecting the `duplicateClientNameValidator` is called . however it is not getting called . really appreciate any help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have declared the formgroup incorrectly . once i changed as below it started to work fine.

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
    aliases: this.fb.array([])
   },{validator: [duplicateClientNameValidator('aliases')]});
```